# Return Largest Numbers in an Array, what did I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, numbers

Return an array consisting of the largest number from each provided sub-array. For simplicity, the provided array will contain exactly 4 sub-arrays.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  let numArr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   let num = Math.max(...arr[i]);
   numArr.push(num);
 }
  return Math.max(...numArr);

}
largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Comment: *Return an array consisting of the largest number from each provided sub-array.* so just return the `numArr` instead of calling `Math.max` with it at the end

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return `numArr` at the end instead of calling [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) on it again:

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    let numArr = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        let num = Math.max(...arr[i]);
        numArr.push(num);
    }
    return numArr;
}

console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

Alternatively you could consider using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const largestOfFour = arrs => arrs.map(arr => Math.max(...arr));
console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I don't know why i used Math.max() again later lol .. I love your map() method too!!!